# jQuery: Show Hide Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble getting the link to be '(show)' or '(hide)' when I click on the link to either hide or show  the paragraph text.

Here's the code I got that won't work:

```
var old_text = $(this).text();
var new_text = (old_text === '(hide)') ? '(show)' : '(hide)';
var toggle_link = $("<a href='#'> "+ new_text + "</a>");
$(this).after(toggle_link);
toggle_link.on('click', function (event){
  $(this).siblings('p').toggle();
});
$(this).after(toggle_link);
```

In the above code. I am toggling the show and hide link on and off, however the text isn't changing.  It just remains ('hide').

Comment: $(this) is referring to a  $("div.article h2").each(function(){} click event.

Comment: Ok than, what does the `H2`  has to do with  the dynamically generated `a` element?

Comment: By a user experience, if I click on that heading (H2) than why to show some (hide) link after it ?

Comment: Please set up a jsfiddle. I am totally lost in this code.

Comment: Yes each h2 is related, I can paste the entire code if that helps.

Comment: You're inside a `H2` elements each, now, tell me what will than in the code `old_text = $(this).text();` return? the `H2` element **text** or the `A` element **text**? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var toggle_link = $("<a href='#'>(hide)</a>");
        $(this).after(toggle_link);
        toggle_link.on('click', function (event){
          $(this).siblings('p').toggle();
            var old_text = $(this).text();
            var new_text = (old_text === '(hide)') ? '(show)' : '(hide)';
            $(this).text(new_text);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to toggle between show and hiding text or link.
Lets suppose you want to toggle the paragraph by clicking some link here its how you do it.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a id="toggle" href="#" style="font-size:20px;">Click Me to show the Paragraph</a>
<p id="toggle1">This is the Paragraph for the sake of this demo. Click the above link to Hide me.</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

        $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $("#toggle1").toggle('slow');
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I Hope this is what you want cuz your question is unclear..